# use different model in the partial view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, view, partial-views

I have a view `view1.cshtml` that uses a `ClassA` as a model, and in the `view1` there is a partial view .. I want the partial view to use `ClassB` as a model.

is that possible ?

**EDIT** add `classB`

```
public class Device
    {

        public int DeviceId { get; set; }

        public string SerialNo { get; set; }

        public string IMME { get; set; }

        public string RefNo { get; set; }

        public string Supplier { get; set; }

        public string Brand { get; set; }

        public string ModelNo { get; set; }

        public DateTime PurchaseDate { get; set; }

        public DateTime RegisterDate { get; set; }

        public string Notes { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<ContractsDevice> ContractsDevices { get; set; }
    }
```

and here the Action method:

```
[HttpGet]
        public ActionResult AssignDevice()
        {
            //list of devices
            List<Device> dev = new List<Device>();
            dev.Add(new Device { Brand = "Samsung" });
            dev.Add(new Device { Brand = "SONY" });

            return PartialView();
        }
```

and here the partial view :

```
<div class="modal-header">
    <h4 class="modal-title">Assign Device</h4>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
    Devices list here
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes it is, how are you calling the partial though?

Comment: @DavidG using `@{Html.RenderPartial("AssignDevice");}`

Comment: For a start, you don't need so much punctuation there: `@Html.RenderPartial("AssignDevice")` is enough and cleaner. Second, I forgot to ask where is the `ClassB` model?

Comment: @DavidG I updated the question and added the `classB`

Comment: Sorry, I meant where is the *instance* of ClassB?

Comment: @DavidG question updated, thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly what you actually need for the view is `List<Device>` and not just `Device` so your view should be something like this:

```
@model System.Collections.Generic.List<Device>

<div class="modal-header">
    <h4 class="modal-title">Assign Device</h4>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
    @foreach(var device in Model)
    {
        <div>@device.SerialNo</div>
    }
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
</div>
```

Secondly you're actually calling this as a child action, not strictly just a partial. So you should be calling it form the parent view like this:

```
@Html.Action("AssignDevice")
```

Finally, don't forget to return your data in the action:

```
return PartialView(dev);
```

Comment: thank you very much it worked, thanks for your time.